# print pdf in both sides

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, pdfsharp

So, i'm using the PDFSharp lib, and, I whant to print a pdf on both sides....
My printer is a hp2055dn I have tryed all things... btw... my code is that:

```
using PdfSharp.Pdf.Printing;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace impressao
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PdfFilePrinter.AdobeReaderPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 8.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe";
            //PdfFilePrinter.AdobeReaderPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe";

            PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
            settings.Collate = false;
            settings.Duplex = Duplex.Vertical;

            PrintDialog printerDialog = new PrintDialog();
            printerDialog.AllowSomePages = false;
            printerDialog.ShowHelp = false;
            printerDialog.PrinterSettings = settings;
            printerDialog.AllowPrintToFile = true;
            printerDialog.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
            DialogResult result = printerDialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                PdfFilePrinter printer = new PdfFilePrinter("0.pdf", settings.PrinterName);

                try
                {
                    printer.Print();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If have a another way to make this, another lib, or, another settings, or another dll... please tell me
if is possible to make a another program in C or C++ and I just pass the parameters to print... I don't know...

I'm needing a lot of it, and urgently :(

Thanks
Alexandre

Comment: Surely this is a printer setting, and not something you are going to control in the code?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I have created a new printer and seted on defaults with print in both sides...